# superfish settings not visible

Tags: navigation

I'm having a strange problem with the Superfish module. If I go to blocks > superfish menu > configure, I only see Pages, Pages Exclude, and Content Types. There's no other settings. I was somehow able to put the main menu into the Superfish 1 menu, but none of the settings are visible. I have the superfish library in `/sites/all/libraries`, and the superfish module in `/sites/all/modules`.

I'm using Navin, a subtheme of Omega.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Would the mongodb module have anything to do with it? I know it affects the block settings

Comment: Any errors showing up in your error logs you can report? Have you flushed cache?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the mongodb block module disabled the normal block module. When I re enabled the block module, and disabled the mongodb block module, it worked fine.